# Why is the branch not listed in Eclipse-SourceReference for git

Tags: eclipse, git, tycho

I am using Tycho for my Eclipse OSGi projects, and noticed that for project in Git the Eclipse-SourceReferences header doesn't include the branch. I *assume* it's because I'm not understanding something about Git as to why the branch isn't necessary. But using just the repo URI, the repo path, and the commit Id, how am I assured I also have checked out the correct branch? If that sounds like a silly question .. a branch is a pointer to the tip commit. So what if the commit Id in the SourceReferences header is the tip of multiple branches?

Answer (score 1):

The `Eclipse-SourceReferences` header is for pointing at the exact sources used to compile that version of the plug-in. It has never held any greater meaning about the original SCM, such as which branch that commit (or CVS tag) came from.

Comment: Right, so if I'm trying to get a copy of the source for a plugin in my Target Platform, using the SourceReferences header, don't I need to know the branch to check out after I've cloned? If the commit isn't on master will 'git checkout _commit_' know what branch to checkout? Even if there's more than one branch pointer for it?